# Fix Kendo UI Grid Pagination style

Tags: css, pagination, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, telerik-mvc

I have recently updated my Kendo UI DLLs on my project, and now on all my grids, the pagination style has changed dramatically.

BEFORE:

[image]

AFTER:

[image]

What can I do to regain the old pagination style?

Comment: Did you also update the references within your project? Such as the layout page.

Comment: @ShawnOrr Yes. The only thing that really changed in the layout page was the addition of a reference to bootstrap.min.js. Removing it did not change anything.